# Can I connect to MongoDB from a remote class by passing a reference to a Mongo connection?

Tags: php, mongodb, scope, kohana

I'm using Kohana's php framework (2.x) and I want to have a helper that lets me access Mongo through a function and return the results as an object. For this to actually query the database, do I have to connect to the database in the local class? Or can I pass `$this->mongo->collection` from a connected object? I'm sure I have errors and misconceptions in my code so feel free to point that out.

```
class mongoaccess
{   

function __construct()
{     
        try
        {
            //$m = new MongoClient();       // not sure how to go about the connection
            //$this->mongo = Mongo_Database::instance();
        }
            catch (Exception $e) 
            {
                error_log('Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
            }
}

    /** 
    * Converts an array to an object. 
    * Multiple nesting supported.
    * @param $array | type: array | Ex: array('newvariable' => 'value')
    */
public static function arrayToObject($array) 
    {
        $object = new stdClass;
        foreach($array as $key => $value) 
        {
            if(is_array($value)) 
            {           
                $object->{$key} = arrayToObject($value); //Recursive
            } else {$object->{$key} = $value;}
        }
      return $object;
    } 



    /** Provides easy access to findOne()
     * @param $collection | type: object member | Ex: $this->mongo->usersinapps
     * @param $query | type: array | Ex: array('keyy' => 'valuee')  
     */
public static function getObjectFromMongo($collection, $query) 
{
    if (empty($query) || !is_array($query) || empty($collection))
        {return null;}

     $collection->findOne($query);

             $object = new stdClass();
     $object = mongoaccess::arrayToObject($query);

     return $object;
}

    // needs review
    /** Provides easy access to find() - iterates through cursor and returns array of objects
     * @param $collection | type: object member | Ex: $this->mongo->usersinapps
     * @param $query | type: array | Ex: array('keyy' => 'valuee')  
     */
public static function getObjectsFromMongo($collection, $query)
{
    if (empty($query) || !is_array($query) || empty($collection))
        {return null;}

    $objectArray = array();

    $mongoResultsCursor = $collection->find($query);

     while ($mongoResultsCursor->hasNext())
     {
        $document = $mongoResultsCursor->getNext();
        array_push($objectArray, $document);
     }

    $object = mongoaccess::arrayToObject($objectArray);

    return $object;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Mongoaccess
{   
    protected $_mongo;

    function __construct()
    {
        $database     = 'test';
        $connect      = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/'.$database);
        $this->_mongo = $connect->{$database}; // $this->_mongo
    }

    function get($collection, $criteria)
    {
        $data = $this->get_many($collection, $criteria);

        return ($data) ? reset($data) : $data; // Get first array
    }

    function get_many($collection, $criteria, $findOne = FALSE)
    {
        $find      = $this->_mongo->{$collection}->find($criteria);

        // find().limit(1) faster than findOne()
        // http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7587
        $find      = $findOne ? $find->limit(1) : $find;

        // Array to object
        // https://coderwall.com/p/k-bwtq
        $data      = json_encode(iterator_to_array($find));
        $to_object = json_decode($data);

        return $to_object;
    }
}
```

---

```
Mongoaccess::get('collection', $criteria_array);
Mongoaccess::get_many('collection', $criteria_array);
```